# drupal 7 | db_select | date_field condition

Tags: date, drupal, conditional-statements

On hook_user_login I want to delete nodes owned by the logged in user of a given content type which are older than 21 days.

The code below works fine (without date condition):

```
function mymodule_user_login(&$edit, $account) {
  global $user;
  $myuid = $user->uid;
  $mytype = 'testdelete';
  $mydate = '2016-07-06 18:45:00';

  $results = db_select('node', 'n')
        ->fields('n', array('nid'))
        ->condition('type', $mytype)
        ->condition('uid', $myuid)
        ->execute();

  foreach ($results as $result) {
    $nids[] = $result->nid;
  }

  if (!empty($nids)) {
    node_delete_multiple($nids);
    drupal_set_message(t('%count nodes has been deleted', array('%count' => count($nids))));
  }
}
```

Now I stuck since over a week with the date condition. My date field is in content type "testdelete" is called "datum" and widget is popup calendar.

I've tried:

```
->fields('n', array('nid','field_datum'))
```

and

```
->fields('n', array('nid','datum'))
```

Both result in an exception:

```
PDOException: SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'n.field_datum' in 'field list': SELECT n.nid AS nid, n.field_datum AS field_datum FROM {node} n WHERE (type = :db_condition_placeholder_0) AND (uid = :db_condition_placeholder_1) ; Array ( [:db_condition_placeholder_0] => testdelete [:db_condition_placeholder_1] => 4 ) in mymodule_user_login()
```

How should the condition look:

```
->condition('datum', $mydate,'<')
```

while $mydate should be something like: `now() -21 days`

**Additional Question:**

I fear hook_user_login is not the right place for this job or is that ok?
Should I use instead something like hook_cron?

Comment: Why not post in [Drupal Answers](http://drupal.stackexchange.com/)?

Comment: sorry - i will do so next time

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To select a collection of nodes based on field values you should use [`EntityFieldQuery`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes%21entity.inc/class/EntityFieldQuery/7.x) instead of `db_select()`.  `db_select()` is a simple query writing tool that assumes you know the storage structures being used in the database. EntityFieldQuery is intended to abstract away the data storage and allow you to only know about the content type structures.

In your case it would look something like:

```
$query = new EntityFieldQuery();

$query->entityCondition('entity_type', 'node')
  ->entityCondition('bundle', 'testdelete')
  ->entityCondition('uid', $myuid)
  ->fieldCondition('field_datum', 'value', $mydate, '<')

$results = $query->execute();
```

As for `hook_user_login()` vs `hook_cron()` that depends on your goal. If you want the content to be deleted after your timeline regardless of user activity `hook_cron()` is a better option. If you want the content to remain until the user returns than `hook_user_login()` is the right tool.

Using `hook_user_login()` it is possible that if you have users generating lots of content that needs to be deleted on login that you will have trouble handling all the required tasks in a timely manner.  If that's the case you'll want to look at creating a batch job or using Drupal's task queue to have Drupal due the time intensive work that doesn't force a user to wait for it to complete.

Answer (score 1):

The db_select query you have is just selecting from the node table.
But, field values are stored in their own tables.
To do a db_select with the date field, you will have to join the datnum fields table.
eg (not tested):

```
$query = db_select('node', 'n');
$query->join('field_data_field_datnum', 'datnum', 'n.nid = datnum.entity_id');
$query->fields('n', array('nid'));
$query->fields('datnum', array('datnum_value'));
// add conditions here
```

A better option is to probably use [EntityFieldQuery](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes%21entity.inc/class/EntityFieldQuery/7.x).
How to use EntityFieldQuery can be seen [HERE](https://www.drupal.org/node/1343708)

As for doing it in HOOK_user_login, it really depends on your situation.
Doing it on user login is probably not a good idea on a high traffic site.
I would do it on HOOK_cron.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you both,

@acrosman - i used your approch with two little changes

```
->propertyCondition('uid', $myuid,'=')
```

and a " ; "  at the end of

```
->fieldCondition('field_datum', 'value', $mydate, '<');
```

For all other with maybe the same problem
my code on initial question to delete the nodes

```
foreach ($results as $result) {
    $nids[] = $result->nid;    }
```

and so on..... didn't work anymore

i used the following code, which works fine

```
foreach($results['node'] as $node){
    node_delete($node->nid);
}
```

Thank you all
Tom